# Azure create data disk and copy files to it

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to create a data disk, copy files to it, and then attach it to an existing virtual machine on Azure? What would be the broad steps for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a data disk, copy files to it, and then
>   attach it to an existing virtual machine on Azure?

For now, we can't copy files to Azure VM data disk direct. The only way we can copy files to the data disk is mount(attach) this data disk to a Azure VM.

> A data disk is a VHD that's attached to a virtual machine to store
>   application data, or other data you need to keep.

If you just want to copy files to one storage and share the files to this VM, as a workaround, we can use [Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-file-how-to-use-files-windows) to share your files to Azure VM.

Another way, we can create a VM in your on-prem Hyper-V, and create a data disk then copy your files to this data disk, then use this data disk to create a VHD, then use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) or powershell to upload this VHD to Azure, and attach this VHD to your Azure VM.

**Note**: For now, each data disk has a maximum capacity of 4095 GB.

Comment: Would it be possible to run a remote script on a vm that downloads a big file (from blob or file storage) to that vm?

Comment: Yes, we can use powershell or CLI 2.0 to download Azure blob to azure VM.  Also we can use Azcopy (only work for windows)to download blob to azure VM.

Comment: @lason, if your Azure VM is windows, we can install Azcopy to it, then we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#file-download) to download blob.  and follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-download) to download blob. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks, is there a solution for Linux as well?

Comment: @lason For Linux, we should install Azure CLI 2.0. about install CLI 2.0, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli). about download blob, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli#create-and-manage-blobs), If it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer so that that other community members will be benefited. 
thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will have to create the VHD locally then upload it to a storage account.

It is **not** possible to locally mount a VHD in Azure blob storage at this time. You can create a VHD mount it to a VM in Azure and copy files from the VM to it if creating and uploading the VHD is prohibitive.

A guide on how to do this with unmanaged disks can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-portal).

You can upload the VHD to blob storage with [Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) or [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

Comment: At what point when locally creating a vhd willI be able to copy the files to it?

Comment: If you are on Window 8 and later you can mount the VHD with a simple double click.